# Fixed width and height of html index opening from new_blank

Tags: html, fixed

I've searched around and couldn't find what I'm looking for. My problem is the following:

I have a website and this website has a seccion that's all ON AIR in which there is a flash player and some links, which both are placed inside a column in the center of an html page.

http://www.radiolacrema.com/envivo

This web page is accessed from this link. From browser and from an image displaying the ON AIR within the home of the website, when clicked from home it opens in a new_blank and I wish for it to open in a fixed width + height ( 430x800 ) and also have the background fixed to that size.

Is this possible? I've tried using the following:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 420px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
```

containing the whole body structure but had no luck, it sticks to the left and the browser window is still maximized, also the background.

hope you can understand what a I need help with. I just want people to click on the image and have a pop up open with fixed width, fixed height and not the full window, so they can

Comment: can we see the javascript code for the click event?

Comment: it is fixed with the wordpress theme, gives option for same page or new_blank, for this only image widget, but i can use a ordinary html block for the same image and have it get clicked from there, then i would be able to add the javascript for fixed width, you just made me realize this, but, is there no way to do this from the html file itself ( the one that gets opened when clicked) ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but check out the demo below.

CSS:

```
body {

background-image: url(http://www.radiolacrema.com/fondo21.jpg);

position:fixed;

}

.container {
margin-left:400px;
margin-top:50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("[class~='floatNoWrap']").each(function () {
$(this).css("width", $(this).outerWidth());
});

});
```

jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LynchJustRules/EfJ9j/

After doing some research, I don't think you can resize the browser window in Chrome, so if you want specific sizes for tablets and mobile devices, you should check out the @media CSS tricks here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/